# Counting the number of weeks in a txt file

Tags: java, text, count

I am reposting this because i feel i didn't word it correctly

I am trying to find the percentage of weeks with an average temperature of 90 or above.

the text file looks like:

```
1/1/2009 76.0 81.1 68.1 86.7 99.2 97.5 92.9
1/8/2009 61.0 86.2 99.3 74.2 89.5 100.2 80.7
1/15/2009 95.7 76.2 92.1 66.5 66.7 80.2 76.3
1/22/2009 97.5 63.0 77.3 71.9 84.8 73.8 80.7
```

....for a total of 39 weeks

How can i find the average temperatures for each week?

we are supposed to use a for loop to read the 7 temperatures but i do not even understand how to get started.

this is what i have so far

```
 while (scan.hasNextLine())
 {
 count++;
 scan.nextLine();
 }
 for (

 System.out.println("Temperature Statistics:");  
 System.out.println("Number of weeks: " + count);
 System.out.println("Weeks with an average of 90 or higher: "+averageAbove);
```

Comment: Count rows? FYI java and javascript are different languages.

Comment: Im wondering if you're trying to figure out how to count the number of weeks between the first row and the last row? IE: #weeks between 1/1/2009 and 1/22/2009. would be something like 3 weeks 1 day. What kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: i am trying to count each row i believe because the text file has each week and the average temperatures for each day. The output would be Number of weeks:

Comment: Use readline to go through file and increments a counter in the loop?

Comment: can you look at my new edit

Comment: Move `System.out.println(count);` outside the `while` loop.

Comment: @user2985204 Look at my update.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you can count the number of rows in the text file:

```
LineNumberReader  lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("YourFile.txt")));
lnr.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println("Number of weeks: " + lnr.getLineNumber());
```

**EDIT:**

Due to your question udpate, this is what you can do in order to *only* print the total number of the weeks instead of printing each week:

```
 while (scan.hasNextLine())
 {
   count++;
   scan.nextLine();
 }

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: i have found those searching but the problem is we haven't been taught this in our class so we cant use it.

Comment: Im trying to count the number of weeks in the file. so if i could count how many of the dates like: 1/1/2009 are on the file it would work

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking to simply count the number of lines in a text file?

If so, the following code will do it, however it's not very efficient.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
int count = 0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   count++
}
br.close();
System.out.println("Number of weeks: " + count);
```